# Turn columns into rows when creating cross table using R?

Tags: r

I am using dataset 'diamonds' from the "tidyverse" package.
I need to create a cross-table of median prices based on the three categorical variables 'cut' (with 5 levels), 'color2' (2 levels) (this was created by defining "good" corresponding the best 3 levels of 'color' and 'bad' corresponding the rest 4 levels), and 'carat3' (3 levels) (this was created by dividing 'carat' value range into 3 intervals).
The 6 columns of the resulting table must be respectively for the 'bad' and the lowest level of 'carat3', the 'good' and the lowest level of 'carat3', etc.
However, the result of my code is the cross-table in which 'cut' becomes the column, not 'carat3' and 'color2' as expected.
Here is my code:

```
diamonds %>% group_by(cut,color2, carat3 = cut_number(carat,3)) %>%
      summarise(price = median(price, na.rm = T)) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = cut,
                  values_from = price,
                  values_fill = 0)
```

[image: The image attached is the result returned by my code]
Could somebody tell me what went wrong with my code? Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you include the code that you used to make `color2`? Otherwise it is hard to reproduce the outcome, even though the data is available. Nevertheless, my guess is that you want to set `names_from = c(carat3, color2)` to get what you want.

Comment: Hi here is how I create color2: `diamonds %>% mutate(color2 = ifelse(color %in% levels(diamonds$color)[1:3],"good","bad"))`
and your sugestion works. Thank you so much!